# How to typize the Function.prototype?

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6

I have the following code:

```js
export type Ctor<T> = new (...args: any[]) => T;

export construct<T>(BaseCtor: Ctor<T>, ...keys: (keyof T)[]): Ctor<Pick<T, keyof T>> {
   const Constructor: Ctor<any> = class extends BaseCtor {
      // Code goes here..
   }
   return Constructor;
}
```

Somewhere else I have:

```js
export const PersonCtor = construct(Person, 'name', 'age');

export class PersonRegistry<PersonModel, typeof PersonCtor.prototype> {
   // Code goes here..
}
```

The question is how to change the type of `PersonCtor.prototype` from `any` to `Pick<Person, 'name' | 'age'>`. Is this possible through implementing an interface like this below and how exactly if so?

```js
interface TypizedPrototype<T> extends Function {
   prototype: T;
}
```

Thank you for your answer!

Kapri

Comment: What is `Person`? What is the point of `Pick<Person, 'name' | 'age'>`?

Comment: Use a [construct signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#construct-signatures) next to the `prototype` property. Don't extend `Function`.

Comment: Hi Bergi! `Person` is a DTO. Hmm I'll give it a try the way you suggest.. Thank you! :)

Comment: No, I mean how is `Person` implemented/defined? It's not an object, it's a constructor according to your types. Why do you need to `Pick` from it?

Comment: Exactly, its the constructor of a DTO.

Comment: Then I still don't understand what `PersonCtor = construct(Person, 'name', 'age')` achieves and why it couldn't be just `PersonCtor = Person`.

Comment: Ok, `Person` is a DTO with almost 70 properties and I want to trunkate it as you can guess from the signature of the method `construct(...)`. For this reason I am trying to typize the `prototype` of the `PersonCtor` so that it has the correct type which should be `Pick<Person, 'name' | 'age'>`.

Comment: Ok, but if you want to truncate it I don't see how `class extends BaseCtor` can work.

Comment: Please consider modifying the code in this question so as to constitute a [mcve] which, when dropped into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground](https://tsplay.dev/wXR08m), clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing.  This will allow those who want to help you to immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it.  And it will make it so that any answer you get is testable against a well-defined use case.

Comment: I agree with @Bergi; you can type this thing however you want (especially with [type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions)), but you are asking for trouble if you are using `--strict` typing and ever pass in a constructor for a class that has methods depending on the missing properties.  And if you never do this, why do you need a class constructor at all?  Why not use a plain object instead?

Comment: I solved my issue following another way. In TypeScript there is a `InstanceType` which I use as follows to generate my second generic type for the class: `InstanceType<typeof PersonCtor>`. Anyways thank you for your effort to help me! :)